# How to use clojure's compile function with a script containing :gen-class?

Tags: compilation, clojure, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

After 3 days of frustration I must ask for help. Being quite new to clojure I want to compile this script from the REPL using (compile 'examples.hello) adapted from AOT page of clojure.org:

```
(ns examples.hello
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [greetee]
  (println (str "Hello " greetee "!")))
```

I use JEdit with the clojure console plugin as my editor and for serious projects leiningen.

My dir structure in $HOME is:
clojure-1.3.0   (edited to save space)

```
|-- classes
|-- clojure-1.3.0.jar
|-- clojure-1.3.0-slim.jar
|-- src
|   |-- examples
|   |   |-- hello.clj
|   |   `-- hello.clj~
|   |-- jvm
|
```

The error msg is:

```
FileNotFoundException Could not locate examples/hello__init.class or examples/hello.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:430)
```

Some questions:

a) If I am compiling why should the compile function look for the very class files I am attempting to create?

b) What are the 'correct' steps to make the compile function work? c) In my Internet search on this problem there are many reference to 'the classpath' or 'your classpath'; is it correct to assume that classpath refers to clojure.jar  etc. and the scripts one is working on and not to java $CLASSPATH which supposedly has been unnecessary since java 1.5?

Comment: what is the command you are running that is giving the error above?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the awkward answer, but I do not yet understand Clojure builds as well as some other languages. So, please bear with me. I am writing this answer from the point of view that you are using a build tool like lein.

Your main -- mine is addr-verify -- must be in the name space specified by the project.clj that accompanies your project. So my main module is core.clj, and it declares its name space as addr-verify, and for lack of a better term declares or uses gen-class.

My project.clj denotes that main is addr-verify.

One of the nice things about lein to build Clojure applications, is it sets all this up for you when you create a project, for example `lein create my-test-proj` .

Here are the pertinent lines from my ./addr-verify/project.clj

```
(defproject addr-verify "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO: add summary of your project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.2.4"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [clj-http "0.1.3"]]
   :aot [addr-verify]
   :main addr-verify)
```

Here are the first few lines from ./addr-verify/src/addr_verify/core.clj

```
(ns addr-verify
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
  (:require [clojure.contrib.str-utils :as ustr])
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
  (:use clojure-csv.core)
  (:use [clojure.tools.cli])
  (:import java.util.Date)
  (:import java.lang.Thread)
  (:import java.io.File)
```